# How to hide the default style scroll bar, when I use overflow:scroll;

Tags: javascript, html, css

The effect I want to achieve is to be able to scroll the page, but do not scroll bar

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-still-being-able-to-scroll/16671476#16671476

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To hide the default scrollbar you can use:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none; 
}
```

I had this problem before, and the above worked in all browsers except IE, so there is a 'hack' you can use:

```css
body, div, html{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
body{
    overflow:hidden;
    position:fixed;
}
div{
    overflow-y:scroll;
    position:relative;
    right:-20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    content<br />
    content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />
    
</div>
```

This allows there to be no scrollbar but keep the content scrollable.